# Proper way to slice in python - e.g. use [1:] or [1:index which is out of range]?

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list, let's say:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I want to slice it so I have all items but the first.
Let's assume I won't change the list ever.

What is (more) correct?

```
lst[1:]
```

or

```
lst[1:4]
```

Seems like I shouldn't use index 4, because it doesn't exist.

Comment: `lst[1:]`............

Comment: First choice works, the other not. I don't think you need to ask the question on StackOverflow to have your answer. ;)

Comment: One of those is shorter, the other involves unnecessary calculations. Take a guess.

Comment: @IkeBell my bad. I just feel like using an index out of range should not work, so the python interpreter in my head is returning me an exception. It kinda answers your question :).

Comment: To all people who downvoted my question. In Codecademy's python course, when they first teach you how to slice, they recommend to use the lst[1:4] way. It's a legit question and maybe you all should reconsider your votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lst[1:]` is more idiomatic. [Here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/optparse.py#l1362) is an example from the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is definitely the best one (and actually the only valid solution). If you use `lst[1:4]`, you make assumptions about the length of `lst`. It does not work anymore if you initialize your list like :
    lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

Answer : `lst[1:]`